# Animating a view to be stacked on top of the view it is behind

Tags: android, android-animation

In my Android app, I have a view behind another view in a `FrameLayout`. I'd like to animate the hidden view at times so that it appears above the view that's shown. Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/options_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            android:gravity="right"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/option_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:text="@string/option_button"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/commentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/commentText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/commentSubmit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/light_gray"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/submit_comment"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ideally, when I start typing in `commentText`, `options_container` would animate up above `commentContainer`. It seems like when I try to animate `options_container` though, nothing really happens. Just to check, I tried:

```
view.animate().y(200);
```

And I didn't see a change. Is this because what I'm trying to do is stack a view on top of another (by way of animation) inside of a `FrameLayout`?

Comment: u forgot to call start on the view property animator i.e. view.animate().y(200).start();

Comment: @vishnus according to the docs, `start()` is optional: "Calling start() is optional because all animations start automatically at the next opportunity. However, if the animations are needed to start immediately and synchronously (not at the time when the next event is processed by the hierarchy, which is when the animations would begin otherwise), then this method can be used."

However I tried that and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, vishnus's comment is right that you need to call start() to make the animation work.

But even you do that, it won't work because the code is just moving the view along the y axis. What you really need is animate().z() which is added in API 21.

Comment: You're right. `z()` would work, but I probably wasn't clear. What I'm trying to do is animate the view underneath so it is stacked on top of the other. Is this unachievable with `FrameLayout`?

Comment: FrameLayout is fine, but what kind of "animation" do you exactly expect? Say view A is underneath view B, when A is raising up, the only thing you could see is that at a certain moment, A replaces B, there's really no "animation" effect.

Comment: Yeah, ideally A would be underneath B, then A would slide up and stack on top of B, which wouldn't have moved.

Comment: Not sure what this "slide up" should look like, if you want some fancy animations you might need to implement them yourself, or combine several animations. Because by default a single view moving along z axis will look like nothing happened at all.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was trying with Y originally. Thanks!

Comment: You can try combining alpha, y and z animations on both views.